# Scala: Regular Expression pattern match with curly braces?

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, curly-braces, wml

so I am creating an WML like language for my assignment and as a first step, I am supposed to create regular expressions to recognize the following:

```
//single = "{"
//double = "{{"
//triple = "{{{"
```

here is my code for the second one:

```
val double = "\\{\\{\\b".r
```

and my Test is:

```
println(double.findAllIn("{{ s{{ { {{{ {{ {{x").toArray.mkString(" "))
```

Bit it doesn't print anything ! It's supposed to print the first, second, fifth and 6th token. I have tried every single combination of \b and \B and even \{{2,2} instead of \{\{ but it's still not working. Any help??

As a side question, If I wanted it to match just the first and fifth tokens, what would I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code (Scala 2.12.2 REPL), and in contrary to your "it doesn't print anything" statement, it actually prints "{{" occurrence from "{{x" substring.

This is because `x` is a word character and `\b` matches a **position** between second `{` and `x`. Keep in mind that `{` isn't a word character, unlike `x`.

As per [this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

> It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> 1) Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>   word character
>
> ...

As for solution, it depends on precise definition, but lookarounds seemed to work for me:

```
"(?<!\\{)\\{{2}(?!\\{)".r
```

It matched "first, second, fifth and 6th token". The expression says match "{{" not preceded and not followed by "{".

For side-question:

```
"(?<![^ ])\\{\\{(?![^ ])".r //match `{` surrounded by spaces or line boundaries
```

Or, depending on your interpretation of "space":

```
"(?<!\\S)\\{\\{(?!\\S)".r
```

matched 1st and 5th tokens. I couldn't use positive lookarounds coz I wanted to take line beginnings and endings (boundaries) into account automatically. So double negation by `!` and `[^ ]` created an effect of implicit inclusion of `^` and `$`. Alternatively, you could use:

```
"(?<=^|\\s)\\{\\{(?=\\s|$)".r
```

---

You can read about lookarounds [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Basically they match the symbol or expression as boundary; simply saying they match stuff but don't include it in the matched string itself.

Some examples of lookarounds

- `(?<=z)aaa` matches "aaa" that is preceded by `z`
- `(?<!z)aaa` matches "aaa" that is not preceded by `z`
- `aaa(?=z)` matches "aaa" followed by `z`
- `aaa(?!z)` matches "aaa" not followed by `z`

---

P.S. Just to make your life easier, Scala has `"""` for escaping, so let's say instead of:

```
"(?<!\\S)\\{\\{(?!\\S)".r
```

you can just:

```
"""(?<!\S)\{\{(?!\S)""".r
```

Comment: Thank you ! Haven't tested it yet but care to explain what each chunk of symbols in the parenthesis actually do?

Comment: @user7552492 Those are lookarounds, I added explanation to the answer. Basically they kinda like matching groups (like `"ab(za)k".r` matches "abzak", but you can extract "za" as `match.group(1)`), but without need to extract values programmatically.